# how to know and add Python path which is in vm to editor in host

Tags: python, django, aptana, virtualbox, vagrant

I'm using vagrant and virtualbox which has ubuntu LTS 12.04 . Now I'm trying to use Aptana Studio for development and when I created a project it asks to specify Python interpreter path. I also have python installed in my host os i.e. win 7.

So how do I know which path to add to, to the aptana studio ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `PYTHONPATH` with `Python` or with `UNIX console`:

`Python`:

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH']
```

or

```
os.getenv('PYTHONPATH')
```

or

```
import sys
sys.path
```

`Console`:

```
which python
```

or

```
whereis python
```

Commonly this is on `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: ok which python gave me /usr/bin/python but when I add it to interpreter field it says invalid interpreter. Does this has something to do with this http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html which is about syncing folder in vagrant. Can someone please clarify

Comment: hmm try `/usr/lib/python2.7/`

Comment: still same invalid interpreter

Comment: try `import sys print  sys.path` and the fourth index is the `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: It gave this ['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/
lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist
-packages']
>>>

Comment: try this: ` /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` or this `/usr/lib/python2.7`

Comment: Can you paste the picture of the window please?

Comment: Oh The problem is the name try instead of `python` `Python2.7` and the executable is `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: I don't know, its still the same. When I auto config it, it showed a list which is here http://s23.postimg.org/g3xyzhwaz/image.jpg . But it's windows python I think.

Comment: oh then the executable is `C:\Python27\python.exe`

Comment: are you sure it will work for the python installed in vm also ?? I'm really confused

Comment: I do not know why you want to use `aptana` when you can use `Sublime` with plugins and this configuration of `aptana` will not affect the `pythonpath` on the machine

Comment: was just looking for better option than notepad++. will look into sublime also. BTW it worked but I'm not sure it will work with the vm

Comment: Yes it will work :D `Sublime` is the best choice :D and it's written totally in `Python`

Comment: Yup Just installed it. Its smooth and light and friendly !!! :D  Thanks a lot. Its totally working for me !! Thanks !! Cheers !

Comment: Yes you're welcome I recommend you install `Package install` and then plugins like `SublimeLinter`, `Python Auto-Complete` and here you have  a list of shortcuts  http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_win.html